# Add/Update list in database using Entity framework 6

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2

I have three tables QuestionBank,Question and Answer. " QuestionBank " will have list of Question and " Question " will have list of " Answer ".

QUESTIONBANK :-

> ```
> public class QuestionBank
> {
> public int id { get; set; }
> public string Text { get; set; }
> public string Chapter { get; set; }
> public string Standard { get; set; }
> public List<Question> Question { get; set; }
> public QuestionBank()
> {
> this.Question = new  List<Question>();
> }
> }
> ```

QUESTION :-

> ```
> public class Question
> {
> public int id { get; set; }
> public string Title { get; set; }
> public string QuestionText { get; set; }
> public List<Answer> Answer { get; set; }
> public string CorrectAnswer { get; set; }
> public Question()
> {
>     this.Answer = new List<Answer>();
> }
> }
> ```

ANSWER :-

> ```
> public class Answer
> {
> public int id { get; set; }
> public string AnswerText { get; set; }
> }
> ```

WEB API :- //Edited

> ```
>   private IRepository<QuestionBank> _QuestionBankRepository;  
>   public QuestionController(IRepository<QuestionBank> QuestionBankRepository)
>     {
>         _QuestionBankRepository = QuestionBankRepository;  
>     }
> [HttpPost]
> [Route("Ques/Add")]
>     public Boolean Add(QuestionBank AddQuetionBankData)
>     {
>         var isQuetionBankPresent = _QuestionBankRepository.GetAll(p => p.Text == AddQuetionBankData.Text && p.Standard == AddQuetionBankData.Standard && p.Chapter == AddQuetionBankData.Chapter).FirstOrDefault<QuestionBank>();
>         if (isQuetionBankPresent != null)
>         {
>             /* Add the data in Question and Answer tables  */
>             return false;
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             /* Add the data in all three tables  */
>             return true;
>         }
>     }
> ```

I have this database for the web api. Now I want to add the data in database through    json { "QuestionBank": QuestionBank, "Question": Question, "Answer": Answer } if the row is present in QuestionBank i dont want to add that data in QuestionBank table and only add the data in Question and Answer table with respective foreign keys. I am using the entity frame work and mvc 5 web api. I am stuck at this point. Please if any thing is needed let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Entity Framework way to update is to to `Context.Entry([your object]).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;` providing that the object is of the right type.

```
public Boolean Add(QuestionBank AddQuetionBankData)
{

    bool flag = false;

    var question = this.MapToQuestion(AddQuetionBankData); //map the input to the EF Type Question
    var anwer = this.MapToAnswer(AddQuetionBankData); //map the input to the EF Type Answer

    var isQuetionBankPresent = _QuestionBankRepository.GetAll(p => p.Text == AddQuetionBankData.Text && p.Standard == AddQuetionBankData.Standard && p.Chapter == AddQuetionBankData.Chapter).FirstOrDefault<QuestionBank>();
    if (isQuetionBankPresent != null)
    {
        _context.Entry(question).State = EntityState.Modified;
        _context.Entry(answer).State = EntityState.Modified;
        /* Add the data in Question and Answer tables  */
        flag = false;
    }
    else
    {
        _context.Entry(question).State = EntityState.Modified;
        _context.Entry(answer).State = EntityState.Modified;
        _context.Entry(AddQuetionBankData).State = EntityState.Modified;
        /* Add the data in all three tables  */
        flag = true;
    }

    _context.SaveChanges();

    return flag;
}

private Question MapTo Question(QuestionBank q) //do this for Answers too
{
    var _q = _context.Question.Where(a=>a.Id == q.Id).SingleOrDefault();

    if(_q!=null)
    {
          _q.id = q.id; //this is already true
          _q.Title = q.Title;
          _q.QuestionText = q.Standard; //I guess
    }

    return _q;
 }
```

The EF updates the Entity (the class you pass to the method `Entry()`) accordingly to its Type.

Notice that the position of the `SaveChanges()`: it works like a stored procedure, you do all the updates and the `SaveChanges()` is like the SQL `COMMIT` command.

You should also wrap the SaveChanges in a try/catch to handle errors, and dispose the _context.

**EDIT**

This class has as dependency `IRepository<Question>`, `IRepository<QuestionBank>`, and `IRepository<Answer>`.

You should create an UpdateController(or PublishController or whatever) that gets the three dependencies in the constructor (better a Facade Service), and call the `Add()` method for each one of them.

If you access directly the [raw Database object](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/database-first-development/creating-the-web-application) you could do like I did and use the `Entry()` method for each table.

Comment: Thanks @fra9001 for the quick reply. I have put the _QuestionBankRepository  object clarification in " Web Api ". You are right that i have to use " Context.Entry([your object]).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified; " for update, but i cant find the way as " _QuestionBankRepository " object is referring to " QuestionBank " table.

Comment: Solved the issue by creating the ViewModel for the QuestionBank and Question.